# Find url and link text from string using php code

Tags: php, string

I want to find url and hyper text  from a paragraph

eg:

```
$content = "<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a> The biggest
search engine is google .The lot of people are used google 
<a href="http://google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>The google video 
service is youtube. <a href="http://youtube.com/ncvh/">Youtube</a>.
Google also provide <a href="http:/gmail.com">Gmail</a>.";
```

output like

```
Text        Url                         Count   

Google      htp://google.com             2
Youtube     htp://youtube.com/ncvh/      1
Gmail       htp://gmail.com              1
```

please anyone help me

Comment: What have you tried so far? We're not going to write the code for you, but will help you fix whatever you've attempted.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match("/<a\shref\=\"(.*)\"/",$content,$matches);
```

$matches is an array with all the matches on the regular expression to find links.
each capturing group is an index in $matches.

note that your `<a>` tags are not closed. If they were closed, you can also extract the text from the links:

```
preg_match("/<a\shref\=\"(.*)\">(.*)<\/a>/",$content,$matches);
```

The regular expression that i used are not waterproof. It relies on the use of double quotes and expects href to be the last attribute in the `<a>` tag. You can find optimized regular expressions in online libraries like http://regexlib.com

Comment: If I'd get a dollar for every time I see someone attacking HTML with a RegEx here on SO, I'd be rich as hell. This **won't work**. Yes, it will given the input string, but what if an URI is formatted like `<a title="foo" href="bar"`?

Comment: as I said, 'The regular expressions that i used are not waterproof'. You can find way better ones for this purpose in regex libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I created pretty much html parsers. Best way for me:

`preg_match_all('_<a(.*?)>(.*?)</a_i', $html, &$matches);` to get a attrs and anchor text

`preg_match('_href[\s]*=[\s]*[\'"](.*?)[\'"]_', $attrs, &$href)` to get href

Parsing href to proper url:

```
$url = str_replace(array(" ", "\n", "\r", "\t"), '', $url);
$url_components = parse_url(trim($url));
```